# What is the type of the Row class in Apache POI 2.5.1 jar?

Tags: java, excel, row, apache-poi

I have a code which should read an **excel** file, but I can't figurate out what is the type of the `Row` class, when I want to implement.

Anyone? Thank you! And I can you only an Iterator? No foreach?

The pic:
 [image]

Comment: As Netbeans is suggesting, you need to add import for _com.lowagie.text.Row_

Comment: I found one on the net: `org.apache.poi.ss.` but there is no "ss". And it does not know the iterator method.

Answer (score 2):

The iterator method which returns a `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row` was added into the library some time between versions 3.0.x and 3.7 and as such will not be available in version 2.5.1, you appear to be working with a library that is older than your code examples.  You will Either need to upgrade the library (with any potential knock on effects), or code in the style that the older lib exposed these features.

Answer (score 2):

As the [Apache POI ChangeLog explains](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#2.5.1-FINAL), POI 2.5.1 was released on *2004-02-29* which makes it almost 10 years old now! You really really need to upgrade to a release from this *decade*....

The class you want is [org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html), which was fully introduced in POI 3.5.

I'd suggest you upgrade to either POI 3.9 final, or even better POI 3.10 beta 2 (the latest as of writing). That will fix your missing class problem, as well as delivering a stunning number of bug fixes, as detailed in the [changelog](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html)

Also, as [explained in the POI documentation on iterating rows and cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator), you can use a for loops, eg:

```
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
for (Row row : sheet) {
  for (Cell cell : row) {
    // Do something here
  }
}
```